# angular 12 upgrade - ts source maps missing

Tags: angular-cli, angular12

I just upgraded my dev platform to angular 12 and my source maps are now gone. I have read ammad Khan's similar question, tried everything in the answers, gone through https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#source-map-configuration (which seems lacking in detail...).

I ripped out angular, reinstalled the cli, generated a test app, cleaned out app.component.html and put in a simple banner and button with a single call - no source maps. I am used to seeing a webpack module in the debugger and that is no longer there.

I am obviously doing something wrong and would appreciate any help. Here is the pertinent part of my angular.json:

```
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "sourceMap": true,
        "optimization": false,
        "outputPath": "dist/test",
        "index": "projects/test/src/index.html",
        "main": "projects/test/src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "projects/test/src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "projects/test/tsconfig.app.json",
        "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
        "assets": [
          "projects/test/src/favicon.ico",
          "projects/test/src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "projects/test/src/styles.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": []
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "500kb",
              "maximumError": "1mb"
            },
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "2kb",
              "maximumError": "4kb"
            }
          ],
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "projects/test/src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "projects/test/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "outputHashing": "all"
        },
        "development": {
          "buildOptimizer": false,
          "optimization": false,
          "vendorChunk": true,
          "extractLicenses": false,
          "sourceMap": true,
          "namedChunks": true
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "development"
    },
```

I am running: 'ng serve -c development'. app.component.html looks like this:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <h1>Test...</h1>
</mat-toolbar>

<div class="content">
    <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="evClick()">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

I would expect to be able to see app.component.ts in the debugger but what I see in FireFox is:

[firefox debug panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GI2Gd.png)

again, thanks for any help...

Comment: Were you able to find any solution?